# When using psql to copy from a csv file, a "" for a null column generates an error instead of a null

Tags: postgresql, csv

I'm trying to use copy to copy a large csv file into a postgres table.

A certain integer column is primarily null. In the csv file, this column just has "".

Every column is quoted, which doesn't seem to be an issue for other columns.

I get this error when I try to copy it:

`ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: ""`

I tried setting a NULL clause to '' and "" in my copy statement. '' does nothing, "" generates an error:

`zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"`

I tried using sed to change all "" to " ", but that still doesn't work even when I set the null clause to " ". I still get

`ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: " "`

For now I am able to proceed by sed'ing the column to -1. I don't really care about this column much anyways. I'd be ok to just setting it to null, or ignoring it, but when I tried to take it out of the column definition section of the copy command, postgres yelled at me.

So my question comes down to this: how can I tell postgres to treat "" as a null value?

Thank you.

Comment: quick follow up question: what else could I sed `""` into that would generate a null?

Comment: The typical way to indicate a missing value (null) is to just put nothing into that field. For instance, if you have three columns (A, B and C) and there is no value for *B*, the csv file would contain `"Col A value",,"Col C value". `""` is a string value, not a numeric value, so there's no way for it to be considered one.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to indicate a missing value (null) in a .csv file is to just put nothing into that field. For instance, if you have three columns (`A`, `B` and `C`) and there is no value for `B`, the .csv file would contain `"Col A value",,"Col C value"`. `""` is a string value, not a numeric value, so there's no way for it to be considered one.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the [`force_null`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) option is for:

> Match the specified columns' values against the null string, even if it has been quoted

So assuming the name of the int column is "y":

```
\copy foo from foo.csv with (format csv, force_null (y));
```